# Is there a technical term for a function that takes one argument and returns an object of the same type?

Tags: function, terminology

I'm considering functions of one argument of type T that return an argument of type T. I seem to vaguely recall that there is a name for that sort of function, maybe homo-something. Is there such a term?

Comment: this would be fun to know, but you may want to ask it at http://mathoverflow.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After an hour-long wiki-crawl, it appears that an appropriate term would be "endofunction".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism#Endofunctions_in_mathematics